# Complex Hopf Fibration

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

The Hopf construction gives a circle bundle $p$ : $S^{3}$ → $\mathbb{CP}^1$. The equation of a 3-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is $X^2+Y^2+V^2+W^2=R^2$, where $R$ is the radius of the 3-sphere. We may rewrite this algebraic equation as $|\phi_1|^2+|\phi_2|^2=R^2$, where $\phi_1=X+iY$ and $\phi_2=V+iW$.

Is it possible to find a solution (i.e., expressions for $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$) to the equation $|\phi_1|^2+|\phi_2|^2=R^2$, in terms of three independent variables $Z$, $\overline{Z}$, and $t$, where $Z$ and $\overline{Z}$ are coordinates on $\mathbb{CP}^1$?

Comment: If you could do as you asked *globally*, wouldn't that tell you that the Hopf bundle is (topologically) trivial?

Comment: I should have mentioned that Z and $\overline{Z}$ are local coordinates on $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

Comment: Oh, duh, of course. Then, if you're allowing $t$ to be a (local) coordinate on the circle, this is just expressing the bundle as a local product. So, sure.

Comment: Okay. May I know what the explicit expressions for $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

$$(Z,t) \mapsto e^{it}\big(\frac Z{\sqrt{1+|Z|^2}},\frac1{\sqrt{1+|Z|^2}}\big)\in\Bbb C\times\Bbb C.$$